# AJAX/JQUERY reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX alongside PHP if the AJAX returns a success I want it to reload, but not the whole page, just the part of the page that I am on.

I have managed to get it so that if it returns a success, it posts a message and then does a page reload, but I do not want a full page reload.

```
if (data == 'success') {
    $('#error_notyfi_change_name').css("color", "green");
    $('#error_notyfi_change_name').text("You have created a new rank!");
    $('#confirm_question_change_name').hide();

    location.reload();
}
```

As you can see, this generates a full page reload, but lets say I am on the gangs page, I then click on create new rank section, it opens this up within my gangs page, which is within the total layout. I just want it to refresh the gangs section rather than the full page.

I apologize if I haven't explained myself clearly enough.

Comment: Pass the data to show and do a `$("#container").html(data)`

Comment: In general ajax is used to not require a page reload, which makes it so useful. Why not just updating what you need? It seems that your implementation design should be changed in order to make use of the power of ajax

Comment: The problem I am having is once the message "You have created a new rank!" comes up after a success, if I click away from the page (still within gangs) and click back onto it, the "You have created a new rank!" message is still there, is there anyway this could be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( data == 'success') {
   $('#error_notyfi_change_name').css("color","green");
   $('#error_notyfi_change_name').text("You have created a new rank!");    
   $('#confirm_question_change_name').hide();
       // location.reload();
   $(".divClass").load(location.href + " .divClass"); // reloads only the .divClass from the location.href URL.
}
```